# What happened to my skin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is the skin I downloaded: 
[image]

and this is how it loads in the game:
[image]

I am playing 1.7.10 forge. I have no mods or resource packs installed. Can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: Can you try loading up on 1.8 vanilla?

Comment: Are you playing on Linux, Mac or Win?

Comment: See if it looks alright in 1.8, if so then the issue is that 1.7.10 isn't handeling the 1.8  skin format correctly

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like your skin uses a second layer. In 1.8, a second layer was introduced, and because of that the skin format had to change. In the place where 1.8's skin reader would have decided that was the overlay, 1.7's skin reader displays the top layer as the only one. You'll have to switch to 1.8 to use that skin.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.8, there is a new player model framework: the "Alex" skin. It is a little slimmer than the "Steve" skin, and I believe it is supposed to be more feminine.

From what I can see of your skin, it looks like it is intended to be a more feminine skin. If the skin is relatively new, it was probably made for the "Alex" model, not the "Steve" model which you will have if you are on 1.7.

I suggest either finding a new skin or updating to 1.8 and changing your preference to "Alex" on the Minecraft website.

Comment: It's true that there is a new skin format,  but that not what is causing the OPs issue.  If you acidentally chose the wrong skin format, it will do a bit of adjusting to make it appear correctly,  just with a black line down the back of each arm to fill in the space from the thin arm on the Steve model ;)

Comment: The issue that the OP is seeing is caused when 1.7.10 attempts to load the new 1.8 skin format that has extra overlays